# Getting a free meal at a restaurant by putting an insect in the food

Tags: identify-this-movie

Forgot the name of the movie, but as the title says, it's the only scene I remember from this movie. I also remember that it was a great movie, I think it was made for not so long ago. It was in English, played in the US and it's a comedy.

What I do remember too is that there was a black man, I think, sitting with a bunch of people he's trying to teach some criminal stuff, so later they went to a restaurant and he took an insect from his bag he prepared and put it on the plate, then he called the staff because of their "mistake", so the result was getting a free meal.

Comment: Do you remember the language\country? The genre? (Was it light in tone or serious?)

Comment: English speaking movie ofcourse, played in the Us, and it's Comedy for sure, more like light in tone.

Comment: I THINK the bunch of people hired the black man to teach them some stuff, a lot similar to horrible bosses fyi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's [Tower Heist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0471042/) (2011), where Eddie Murphy's character helps a gang in a heist. You can see him taking a cockroach out to get a free meal at the end of this clip:

Comment: I'll flesh this out because I think you're right.